# After installing OpenGL to run genymotion, Ubuntu 14.04 stopped booting

Tags: 14.04, opengl

now I get error fatal server error
no screens found. This is after I select failsafe X option.

And if I continue normally I get messages like:

Fontconfig warning /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf, line 61: having multiple values in test  isn't supported and may not work as expected.

After this the boot gets stuck!!

Please help, having to type on touch device is just horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer part of this question.

The message `Fontconfig warning /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf, line 61: having multiple values in test isn't supported and may not work as expected.` seems to be the result of a program incorrectly adding the to the file - but is only a warning and not your main issue as it's just a warning.

I can confirm this issue still exists in `16.04LTS` and it appeared after using an updated release of `wine` (`wine-2.4`) and downloading additional font packages (via Wine Tricks).

To fix, simply use you favourite text editor (in my case `vim`), and edit the file `/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fonts.conf`. You'll see several places where you have back-to-back `<string>` tags that need to be broken up. You'll want to go from:

```
<test name="lang" compare="not_eq">
  <string>zh-cn</string>
  <string>zh-sg</string>
</test>
```

to:

```
<test name="lang" compare="not_eq">
  <string>zh-cn</string>
</test>
<test name="lang" compare="not_eq">
  <string>zh-sg</string>
</test>
```

Apparently the fix was pushed 6 years ago according to launch pad [1], so somehow there is still some issue going on here. There also a blog post detailing the fix here (in Chinese) [2].

[1] https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/ttf-wqy-zenhei/+bug/1034928

[2] https://www.cnblogs.com/lishpei/p/6130807.html